# How do I create a Span<T> of length 1 over a single variable (field or ref parameter) of type T

Tags: c#, memory, .net-core

This question is regarding types [`Span<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.span-1?view=netcore-3.0) and [`RealOnlySpan<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.readonlyspan-1?view=netcore-3.0) in .NET Core. The documentation explains how to create a span over an array, or an array segment, or a stack-allocated or unmanaged memory. In some circumstances I would like to create a span of length 1 over a single variable (a field, a `ref` parameter, or `ref` local) to pass it to API that can deal with arbitrary spans. How can I do that?

I imagine there could be a constructor `Span<T>.Span(ref T)`, but apparently there isn't one. Copying the variable into an array and creating a span over that array does not solve the problem, because any modifications of the span would not reflect on the original variable.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
MemoryMarshal.CreateSpan<T>(ref T reference, int length)
```

Passing `1` in as the length argument. Note, this is inherently unsafe* which is why its in the `System.Runtime.InteropServices` namespace.

*Its not checked for validity in anyway, if the length is too long you will overwrite other memory, if you return the span from a method and its a local variable you are in trouble etc.

Answer (score 5):

A safe alternative to the accepted answer, provided your type is a `struct` (Example: `int` value initialized as 123):

```
ReadOnlySpan<int> mySpan = stackalloc int[1] { 123 };
```

If you want a non-readonly span, you can declare your variable as a reference to the first element of the span, like so:

```
Span<int> mySpan = stackalloc int[1] { 123 };
ref var myVariable = ref mySpan[0];
```

Now accessing either the variable or the content of the span will access/write the same value.